# Kendo UI window will not open a view that has a layout

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor, kendo-ui, kendo-ui-mvc

I am using KendoUI for MVC, trying to open a Kendo-UI-Window that loads its content like this:

```
.LoadContentFrom("Edit", "CustomerContact")
.Events(events => events.Open("centerWindow"))
```

When the Edit.cshtml view uses my _DialogLayout.cshtml it will not load. When the Edit.cshtml view has Layout = null the window loads just fine.

The JavaScript error that I am getting when clicking to open the dialog is:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'open' of undefined

Here is my javascript:
.Events(events => events.Open("centerWindow"))

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btnNewContact")
            .bind("click", function () {
                $("#windowContact").data("kendoWindow").open();
            });
    });

    function centerWindow(e) {
        e.sender.center();
    }
</script>
```

Why would the error happen when Edit.cshtml is using the _DialogLayout.cshtml view which is a stripped down verison of _Layout.cshtml. It works completely fine when I create a view with no Layout.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether _DialogLayout.cshtml includes jQuery a second time (typically at the bottom). If so, you need to remove it. It replaces the current jQuery version, and as a result, the data cache you're accessing with `.data("kendoWindow")` is empty.

Comment: Hmm this worked but doesn't make sense to me can you explain? I have 2 layouts _Layout.cshtml and _DialogLayout.cshtml. If _Layout isn't involved at all how is it interfering? Is it because the parent page is loaded so technically the scripts from the parent page are already there from _Layout.cshtml? If this is the case I guess I should remove all scripts/styles from _DialogLayout.cshtml.

Comment: to me it sounded like you're including jQuery and other libs on the edit page itself, but I don't know what your templates look like; then if you use DialogLayout, jQuery will be there twice; I don't think Layout.cshtml gets included if Layout = null; you just need to make that jQuery is only there once, and before the kendo libs; whether it's included in the layout or somewhere else shouldn't matter